# How to check wether a path represented by a QString with german umlauts exists?

Tags: python, pyqt4, diacritics, qstring

i get a QString which represents a directory from a QLineEdit. Now i want to check wether a certain file exists in this directory. But if i try this with os.path.exists and os.path.join and get in trouble when german umlauts occur in the directory path:

```
#the direcory coming from the user input in the QLineEdit
#i take this QString to the local 8-Bit encoding and then make
#a string from it
target_dir = str(lineEdit.text().toLocal8Bit())
#the file name that should be checked for
file_name = 'some-name.txt'
#this fails with a UnicodeDecodeError when a umlaut occurs in target_dir
os.path.exists(os.path.join(target_dir, file_name))
```

How would you check if the file exists, when you might encounter german umlauts?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting no where with this on my Ubuntu box with an ext3 filesystem.  So, I guess make sure the filesystem supports unicode filenames first, or else I believe the behavior is undefined?

```
>>> os.path.supports_unicode_filenames
True
```

If that's True, you should be able to pass unicode strings to the os.path calls directly:

```
>>> print u'\xf6'
ö
>>> target_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), u'\xf6')
>>> print target_dir
C:\Python26\ö
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join(target_dir, 'test.txt'))
True
```

You should look at [QString.toUtf8](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qstring.html#toUtf8) and maybe pass the returned value through os.path.normpath before handing it over to os.path.join

Good Luck!

nm, it works fine on my ubuntu box as well...

```
>>> os.path.supports_unicode_filenames
False
>>> target_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), u'\xf6')
>>> print target_dir
/home/clayg/ö
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join(target_dir, 'test'))
True
```

Comment: I haven't yet been at my job to try things out but i'll definitely give your approach a try. Furthermore i have found this, which offers to leave it completely to PyQt to check for the file and deal with umlauts. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qfileinfo.html#exists